# How to make condition if List is not empty or null in JSP?

Tags: jsp

List from controller received. How to check if it is not `null`, then show some information and else skip show?

```
<c:forEach items="${itemList}" var="item">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<c:if test="${!empty itemList}">
    the list is neither empty nor null
</c:if>
```